# Switching databases in code igniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, switching

I have two databases I need to connect to, which I can do in the controllers and libraries I have written. For some odd reason (i'm assuming I'm just missing something simple here) I can't get it to work in the model all of the sudden. I have read the database class in the CI user guide.

I tried making a reference to $pew when loading pew ($this->pew =& $this->load->database('pew', TRUE)) to no avail.

Any thoughts, suggestions? Thanks!

***Error***

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
/Sites/CI/nyan/application/models/pewpewmodel.php on line 15
```

***Line 15***

```
$this->pew->query('SELECT * FROM ExtractEvent'); //simplified for testing
```

**database.php**:

```
$active_group = 'nyan';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['nyan']['hostname'] = 'catcatcat';
$db['nyan']['username'] = 'mew';
$db['nyan']['password'] = 'meow';
$db['nyan']['database'] = 'meow';
$db['nyan']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

$db['pew']['hostname'] = 'jujubees';
$db['pew']['username'] = 'qwop';
$db['pew']['password'] = 'qwop';
$db['pew']['database'] = 'nom';
$db['pew']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
```

***Model pewpewmodel.php***

```
private $pew; 

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->pew = $this->load->database('pew', TRUE);
}

function get_forms_by_date($id = NULL, $Year = NULL, $Month = NULL, $Day = NULL)
{
    $this->pew->query('SELECT * FROM ExtractEvent'); //simplified for testing
}
```

***Controller nomnom.php***

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('pewmodel');
    $data['Forms'] = $this->pewmodel->get_forms_by_date($this->session->userdata('Username'), date('Y'), date('n'), date('j'));
    $this->load->view('common/header', $data['Forms']);
    $this->load->view('home/index');
    $this->load->view('common/footer');
}
```

***View index.php***

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($Forms); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

[from within the model constructor]

```
        $db['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $db['username'] = 'root';
        $db['password'] = '';
        $db['database'] = 'my_database';
        $db['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
        $db['dbprefix'] = '';
        $db['pconnect'] = TRUE;
        $db['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $db['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $db['cachedir'] = '';
        $db['char_set'] = 'latin1';
        $db['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_bin';
        $db['swap_pre'] = '';
        $db['autoinit'] = TRUE;
        $db['stricton'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->database($db, FALSE, TRUE);
        // False=don't return db object
        // True =use as active record, so it replaces default $this->db
```

Hope this helps coders searching through Google like I did.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->pew = $this->load->database('pew', TRUE);
```

You load a database which doesn't exist in your database-configuration.

Comment: i used two different names above when I pasted the question, whoops, fixed.

Comment: What does var_dump($this->pew); say?

Comment: For some reason, CI doesn't returns a database object. Maybe it can't connect or the group doesn't exist in the config file (maybe a typo). No error message? Nothing in the logs?

Comment: php_error.log - [11-Jul-2011 10:29:54] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
/Sites/CI/nyan/application/models/pewpewmodel.php on line 15

If I switch the name of the database group from pew to nyan (which it loads by default) the connection returns true and can connect to the DB no problem

Comment: just tried using the DSN style

    $dsn = 'mssql://qwop:qwop@jujubees/nom';
    $this->pew = $this->load->database($dsn);

var_dump results:
    bool(false) 
in the constructor and the method. the connection string does work, just not from CI.

I have been writing the same code in two separate projects, I'll check those results in the other project and see if it works there then edit this post.

Comment: i missed something key. I had not been checking the log when I was loading the database and passing TRUE at the end. got this error, to tried loading it on a server that has mssql.so library for sure and it works. ID10T error. Sorry gents

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mssql.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mssql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a 500 error when I passed TRUE to connect like below. I assumed (yeah I know) that I was just having the same problem with connecting. truth be told it was an ID10T error from the beginning. I was missing the mssql.so library on my local machine and another I was testing from.

```
$this->pew =& $this->load->database('pew', TRUE)
```

My apologies for the waste of time gents.